# Page keeps refreshing when I click on a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a page with two buttons connected to two different bootstrap modals. They were all working fine but all of a sudden stopped. Whenever I click on either button now, the page just keeps refreshing as opposed to displaying the respective modal. I do not know what the problem is as there is no error in the console.

The site is hosted on https://storzy.netlify.app/

I have searched high and low but can't seem to find what might be stopping the modal from displaying correctly now.

Please how do I go about stopping the page from refreshing and showing the correct modal instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change the `form` to `div` for your login and signup parents

```
<div class="form-inline mt-3 mt-lg-0">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">login</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary ml-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signupModal">Sign up</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked just fine. Any idea why it was working earlier and suddenly stopped?

Comment: Not sure but the form might have been redirecting to some function that you added latter on in which your button was acting as form submit resulting page reload .

Answer (score 3):

If the button is within a form, the default behavior is submit. If the button is not within a form, it will do nothing.
Hence to avoid the page refresh, add `type="button"` to the buttons to prevent it.

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal" type="button">login</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary ml-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signupModal" type="button">Sign up</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked as well. Appreciate the help!